# iPhone app access log

Tags: iphone, applications, logs

I accidentally brought my iPhone 7 into my university examination and was wondering if I would be able to produce a log (record) of iPhone app access, to show that I never used it during that particular period?

Already found out about something called **iosloginfo** but not too sure if that's relevant to my problem.

Comment: Hi, you may have a look at this: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/System_Log